# "Al horno" vs "al forno"

Tags: traducción

[image: Imagen con las palabras]

Usando mi diccionario favorito leo.org no pude ver cuál es la diferencia entre las dos palabras. Hay una traducción para *horno*, pero no conoce *forno*.

Supongo que hay una diferencia seguramente, véase la imagen arriba.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Date cuenta de que las bolsas de Matutano se venden tanto en España como en Portugal (se fabrican para toda la península ibérica), por lo que los textos vienen en ambos idiomas. Los textos "amendoins" y "no forno" están en portugués.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Cacahuetes al horno" es el nombre del producto en español.
"Amendoins no forno" es el nombre del producto en portugués.

Debido a la proximidad de España y Portugal, la mayoría de comida envasada viene etiquetada tanto en español como en portugués. Lo puedes comprobar en los snacks, en los paquetes de cereales, en los zumos, en la leche, etc.
*Normalmente* el texto en español tiene un tamaño de letra mayor, como en este caso.